# 2 monitors for 2 computers and one keyboard/mouse

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-switch, multiple-computers

So I'm planning on building a new setup, and I'm having a little trouble in getting my head around a couple of things. To simplify things, my setup will have 2 monitors, 1 desktop and 1 work laptop, which won't be connected in all the time. I will have a wired keyboard and a wireless mouse (via wireless dongle).

I have 3 scenarios in which my setup would be used:

1. Both monitors and mouse & keyboard connected to my PC.
2. Both monitors and mouse & keyboard connected to laptop.
3. This scenario is where things get a bit tricky, at least for me. How can I achieve this as simple as possible, without having to unplug and plug cables, dongles, etc:

   If both monitors are connected to either PC or laptop, and I want to quickly have one monitor connected to PC, and the other one to laptop, while being able to control both with the same mouse and keyboard whenever I want (not simultaneously, of course)?

   To give an example for this scenario, say both monitors and keyboard & mouse are connected to work laptop, and I want to quickly have my 2nd monitor connected to my PC instead so I can play YouTube in the background, while maintaining the main monitor connected to my work laptop.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is not really a brainstorming site, but we can provide answers when you have a specific question

Comment: What OS?  For windows, Mouse Without Borders: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460

Comment: Most 2x2 KVM devices only support instant switching from one PC to another across all inputs. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005956572036.html looks like maybe you can independently switch which video input goes to which output, but frankly at that price I don't know what I would expect.